# How to display which file is playing by Media Player from Playlist in vb.net ?

Tags: vb.net, media

I am working on vb.net application of video player using AxWindowsMediaPlayer

I have successfully created Playlist of bunch video files and it plays perfect.

I have more than 2 videos in the playlist.

I want to display message box which that file name when next video file get played from playlist.

Which event should I use ? and how to display which file is playing currently ?

I have used below code for creating playlist.

```
    Private Sub PlayVideos()

        Try


        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "full"


        Dim Playlist As IWMPPlaylist = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("Playlist1")

            Dim VideoFile1 As WMPLib.IWMPMedia3 =  AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(Path1.Trim)
        Playlist.appendItem(VideoFile1)

            Dim VideoFile2 As WMPLib.IWMPMedia3 = AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.newMedia(Path2.Trim)
        Playlist.appendItem(VideoFile2)

  AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentPlaylist = Playlist


        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code should do it .. add it to the PlayStateChange event. The reason I have an empty try..catch statement in there is because while the media player is changing items, the playstatechange event fires several times, but until the next track is loaded, the currentmedia.name property is null and returns System.NullReferenceException. Eventually the currentMedia.name property is set to the new item and everything is happy. There may be a better way to do this, but it works for me.

```
With AxWindowsMediaPlayer1
    Static Dim lasttrack As String = ""
    Try
        If .playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying And .currentMedia.name <> lasttrack Then
            MessageBox.Show("Current playing track is " & .currentMedia.name)
                lasttrack = .currentMedia.name
            End If
        Catch
        End Try
    End With
```

Comment: Not working....where I suppose to write this code  ? there must be some event when next file get played, In that event it supposed to write ?

Comment: If youre not sure how to to this, click on the code tab. At the top of the code window you have a couple of dropdown lists. In the middle one, chose your mediaplayer control. In the right hand one, choosePlayStateChanged. This should create a new eventhandler sub. Just paste the code in there.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the [CurrentItemChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562403(v=vs.85).aspx) event.

Add the following code after setting the `currentPlaylist` property:

```
AddHandler AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.CurrentItemChange,
        Sub(s As Object, cic As AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_CurrentItemChangeEvent)
            Dim new_item As IWMPMedia = cic.pdispMedia

            MsgBox(new_item.sourceURL)
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

playstate change help for check if action change to media player add this to form1

```html
 Private Sub AxWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange
        If (AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying) Then



            TextBox2.Text = "Opening..."
        End If
        With AxWindowsMediaPlayer1
            Static Dim lasttrack As String = ""
            Try
                If .playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying And .currentMedia.name <> lasttrack Then
                    TextBox1.Text = (.currentMedia.name)
                    lasttrack = .currentMedia.name




                End If
            Catch
            End Try
        End With
```